# Record larger than the Split size in AWS GLUE?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I'm Newbie in AWS Glue and Spark.
I build my ETL in this.
When connect my s3 with files of 200mb approximately not read this.
The error is that

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o99.toDF.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 16) (91ec547edca7 executor driver): com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.NonFatalException: Record larger than the Split size: 67108864
```

Update 1:
When split my json file(200mb) with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), in two parts AWS GLUE, read with normally both parts

My solution is a lambda splitting file, but i want to know how aws glue split works
Thanks and Regards

Comment: This is a little bit of a guess here..  But I think its complaining that you have a *record* that exceeds the *file* split size.  What type of files are these?  Maybe you specified the wrong delimiter on a csv?

Comment: Is a JSON file, I thought AWS split large files automatically.

Comment: Glue/Spark will split files, but not records.  Which I think is the issue.  Perhaps there's a way to increase the max split size that will accommodate these large records.  Or perhaps there's a format issue with your JSON

Comment: Uhmm, for example my JSON has 40K Records, so the problem is a JSON format. But with small files (50mb) all good :/